# Integration by parts on the upper half plane

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $g\in C^3(\partial\mathbb{R}^n_+)$ is bounded. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and define
\begin{equation}
u(x) = \frac{2x_n}{n\alpha(n)} \int_{\partial\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{|x-y|^n}g(y) \mathrm{d}y.
\end{equation}
I would like to show that
\begin{equation}
\Delta'(u) = \frac{2x_n}{n\alpha(n)} \int_{\partial\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{|x-y|^n}(\Delta'g)(y) \mathrm{d}y,
\end{equation}
where $\displaystyle \Delta'=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\partial^2_{x_i}$, which is the Laplace operator in $n-1$ variables.

I tried:
\begin{equation}
\partial^2_{x_i}u(x) = \frac{2x_n}{n\alpha(n)} \int_{\partial\mathbb{R}^n} \partial^2_{x_i} \left( \frac{1}{|x-y|^n} \right) g(y) \,\mathrm{d}y.
\end{equation}
Can I use integration by parts like this:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2x_n}{n\alpha(n)} \left[ \int_{\partial(\partial\mathbb{R}^n)} \left( \frac{1}{|x-y|^n} \right) g(y)\nu \,\mathrm{d}S - \int_{\partial\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{|x-y|^n} \partial_{x_i}^2(g(y)) \,\mathrm{d}y \right]
\end{equation}
I am not sure if I do the integration correctly. I don't know what to do with the boundary term. Is it supposed to be 0, but why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary of $\mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}$ is essentially $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Consequently, the boundary of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is where at least one $y_{j}$ is at $\pm \infty$. In this case, the integrand
\begin{equation}
\left( \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n}}\right)g(y)
\end{equation}
vanishes, since we assume that $g$ is bounded. Thus, the boundary term does indeed vanish.

I believe you did the integration by parts mostly correctly except for a sign error. Since you are working with the operator $\partial_{x_{i}}^{2}$, you are essentially applying IBP twice, and so the sign on the integral over $\partial \mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}$ is positive. It is also important to realize that \begin{align*}
\partial_{x_{i}}|x-y|^{-n} & = \frac{-n}{2}|x-y|^{-n-2}2(x_{i}-y_{i})\\
& = n|x-y|^{-n-2}(y_{i}-x_{i})\\
& = -\partial_{y_{i}}|x-y|^{-n}.
\end{align*}
Moreover
\begin{align*}
\partial_{x_{i}}^{2}|x-y|^{-n} & = -n|x-y|^{-n-2} + n(y_{i} - x_{i})\frac{-n-2}{2}|x-y|^{-n-4} 2(x_{i}-y_{i})\\
& = -n|x-y|^{-n-2} + n(n-2)(x_{i}-y_{i})^{2}|x-y|^{-n-4}.
\end{align*}
This is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, and so $\partial_{x_{i}}^{2}|x-y|^{-n} = \partial_{y_{i}}^{2}|x-y|^{-n}$.

It might be easier to work out the details if you wrote out the integral explicitly as an iterated integral. Then it is clear that integrating by parts boils down to applying it over a single variable at a time. Again, the boundary terms will vanish because they involve taking a limit as $y_{i} \to \pm \infty$. In particular,

\begin{align*}
& \int_{\partial \mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}} \partial_{x_{i}}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{|x-y|^{n}} \right)g(y)\,dy\\
& = \int_{y_{n-1} = -\infty}^{\infty} \cdots \int_{y_{1}=-\infty}^{\infty} \partial_{x_{i}}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{|x-y|^{n}} \right)g(y)\,dy_{1}\cdots dy_{n-1}\\
& = \int_{y_{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}} \cdots \int_{y_{i+1}\in \mathbb{R}} \int_{y_{i-1} \in \mathbb{R}} \cdots \int_{y_{1} \in \mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{y_{i} \in \mathbb{R}}\partial_{y_{i}}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{|x-y|^{n}} \right)g(y)\,dy_{i} \right)dy_{1}\cdots dy_{i-1}dy_{i+1}\cdots dy_{n-1}\\
& =  \int_{y_{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}} \cdots \int_{y_{i+1}\in \mathbb{R}} \int_{y_{i-1} \in \mathbb{R}} \cdots \int_{y_{1} \in \mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{y_{i} \in \mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{1}{|x-y|^{n}} \right)\partial_{y_{i}}^{2}g(y)\,dy_{i} \right)dy_{1}\cdots dy_{i-1}dy_{i+1}\cdots dy_{n-1}\\
& = \int_{\partial \mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}} \left(\frac{1}{|x-y|^{n}} \right)\partial_{y_{i}}^{2}g(y)\,dy
\end{align*}